# Why data is getting duplicated while migrating data from Mysql to S3 using multiple trigger for same AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I am using Springboot in AWS Lambda to migrate data from MySQL DB to S3 on a regular interval.
My lambda calls the functions **apply()** which I set in environment variable FUNCTION_NAME in AWS lambda console.

It is working fine when I invoke my lambda with one trigger of cloudwatch event Scheduler.

But to achieve concurrency and complete the task faster as there will be millions of records on prod, I added three trigger at the same time but due to this there is a problem that the same data is moved to s3 three times, once by each lambda.

Although I have annotated my apply() method with @Transactional. Below is the overridden apply() method of Function<T, R> interface of java.util.function.

```
@Transactional
@Override
public String apply(Map map) {
Supplier<Stream<Object>> streamSupplier = () -> repo.getAllRecords();
        try (Stream<Object> responseStream = streamSupplier.get()) {
            List<Object> dataList = new LinkedList<>();
            responseStream.forEach(item -> {
                if(dataList.size() != 30000) {
                    dataList.add(item);
                } else {
                    uploadToS3(dataList);
                    dataList.clear();
                }
                entityManager.detach(item);
            });

       if(dataList.size() > 0) {
            uploadToS3(dataList);
            dataList.clear();
        }
    }
```

This is how I am fetching result from DB

```
@Transactional
@QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "10000"),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
            @QueryHint(name = READ_ONLY, value = "true")
    })
    @Query(value = "select * from table_x",nativeQuery = true)
    public Stream<Object> getAllRecords();
```

I am new in this field. Please help me in understanding why the data is migrated three times even using Transactional?

Comment: where is the logic for lambda wise logical separations like chunk/partitions of records from DB? something lambda some static lambda identifier passed to each of these lambda's event and then fetch records based on that. e.g. lambda exection1 will fetch partition1/chunk1 records, lambda exection2 will fetch partition2/chunk2 records and lambda exection3 will fetch partition3/chunk3 records.

Comment: i haven't done what you are suggesting. But can you please tell why above thing is happening i.e each lambda process all the records separately and why transactional is not working?

Comment: What do you expect `@Transactional` to do? And does that expectation match what its documentation says it will do?

Comment: I want that when one lambda is reading some records from DB then till it doesn't upload to s3 it shouldn't be visible to other lambdas.